# Reading and Writing rich text in JSON format using RestAPI

Tags: rtf

I am trying to read an article description field in JSON format and then, create new article with same description using python based Rest API script. It works fine with plain text. I am facing issue with rich description that contains special character or bullet or table or website link. I suspect issue with encoding/format. Can somebody help,

**Example description:**
Access memory locations more than once

· Using different commands

· Using different formats

**Error**
Response code: 400
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries

**Code Snippet and Flow**

1. Fetch child entries using payloadEQL and place them in JSON

rsp = requests.post(urlEQL, verify=False, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(), headers = headers, data = payloadEQL)

2. Convert JSON into Pandas dataframe and manipulate some entries except description
3. Convert dataframe back to JSON
4. create new article

   response = requests.post(urlDest, verify=False, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(), headers = headers, data = payloadDest)